# Customize Spring Error Message

Tags: java, spring-mvc, customization, illegalargumentexception

I want to change the default error messages being thrown by Spring.

I basically have this form.  Format of the date should follow "mm/dd/yyyy"

```
<p>
    <label class="label">Start Date</label>
    <form:input path="dteStartDate" /> 
    <form:errors path="dteStartDate"/>
</p>
```

Everything works fine, but during binding I get this message added by the form:error tag.

> Failed to convert property value of type [java.lang.String] to required type 
>   [java.util.Date] for property dteStartDate; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>
> Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "2010/11/19"

Can I customize this?  So that instead of these I could show something like this:

> Invalid Date Format.  Format should be "mm/dd/yyyy"

This is Spring MVC 2.5.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to define a [`MessageSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource) to resolve error code to the message. Error codes are built as [described here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html) (so you'll have `typeMismatch.<objectName>.dteStartDate`).