# How do I return user-friendly errors from org.springframework.format.Formatter?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa

I have a few entities which relate to each other in my application, and there are forms where users can set up these relationships. For a simple example, I'll use the concept of a "parent ticket":

```
@Entity
public class Ticket {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Ticket parentTicket;

    // ...
}
```

Elsewhere, I've defined a [`Formatter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/Formatter.html) for my `Ticket` class:

```
@Component
public class TicketFormatter implements Formatter<Ticket> {
    // ...

    @Override
    public String print(Ticket object, Locale locale) {
        return object.getId().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Ticket parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        try {
            return ticketService.getTicket(Integer.valueOf(text));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid ticket #"+text, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, my form has, more or less:

```
<label for="parentTicket">Parent Ticket:</label>
<input type="text" name="parentTicket" id="parentTicket"/>
```

I'd expect that the user would enter the ID number of the ticket to link, and that a blank entry would be treated as `null`.

So, I'd hope that the validation error shown on my form would be "Invalid ticket #[blah]", but instead, I basically get a whole long stack trace...

What's the right way to handle this? Do I need to implement a separate [`Validator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Validator.html) and apply that to my `parentTicket` field? But, wouldn't that validate the `Ticket`, and not the `String` my formatter is failing on? How do I work out this seeming chicken-and-egg problem?

Comment: You should show how you get the `Ticket` in your controller - there are certainly solutions to that problem, but we must know how the formatter is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the best solution I've come across so far: [Customize Spring Error Message](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3270316/151845)

Basically, I just had to [set up a `MessageSource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource):

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages/messages"/>
</bean>
```

Then set some properties in `/WEB-INF/messages/messages.properties`, like:

```
typeMismatch.com.example.domain.Ticket=is not a valid ticket number
```

And then that gets shown as the error message.

You can see more about how this works by inspecting the `BindingResult` object Spring MVC gives you, to find the "[error codes](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-conversion)". This uses [`DefaultMessageCodesResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/DefaultMessageCodesResolver.html) by default.